# Passing variable from android to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

i'm having problem in passing data/variable from android to javascript.here is my code.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_graph);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String temp = "yoolod";
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:sample(\""+temp+"\")");
```

in test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function sample(var){ //this is line 10
       document.write (var);
       //echo var;
 }

</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I always have this, error and can't find solution yet. Hope you can help me.

"Uncaught ReferenceError: sample is not defined", source:  (1)
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var", source: file:///android_asset/test.html (10)

Answer (score 1):

after searching and trial error i somehow found a way. i just put the loadurl where im calling the function inside the onfinished of the webview.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String loc) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:sample('"+temp+"')");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in to the single quotes, below i have changed your code, take that code and try again.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:sample('"+temp+"')");
```

i have set the value (which is getting from the android) in edittext.

so you will get value in to the edit text in html.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<script language="javascript">

 // getting Value from Android/ios
 function sample(temp){  
 var textcontrol = document.getElementById("txtname");
 textcontrol.value = temp;
 }

</script>
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body >
<h1>My HTML </h1>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtname" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried the codes above sir but i still have the error 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: sample is not defined", source:  (1) .
i even tried the html above but still the same. am i missing something sir? thanks

Comment: by the way, i will be using this for the google chart, i pass dynamic data from android to javascript. maybe u could give some tips to better to do it.